# adding header class based on window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to switch header class where the breakpoint is window width less than 1000px.But it works fine when i resize large to small but not in vice versa.

Here is the example of html:

```
<header class="header-1">
  ........
</header>
```

here header class might be `header-1`, `header-2` ...... etc

### and here is js codes:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function(){
    var width = jQuery(window).width();
    var header = jQuery(document).find('header');
    var headerClass = header.attr('class');
    if(width < 1000){
        if( headerClass !== 'header-6' ){
            header.removeClass(headerClass);
            header.addClass('header-xs');
        }else{
            header.removeClass('header-xs').addClass(headerClass);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do that with javascript and not simply with a CSS media query?

Comment: Add an `else` for larger width

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't restore the state while your size is restored. Restore the state in the **else**  condition:

```
jQuery(window).on('load resize', function(){
        var width = jQuery(window).width();
        var header = jQuery(document).find('header');
        var headerClass = header.attr('class');
        if(width < 1000){
            if( headerClass !== 'header-6' ){
                header.removeClass(headerClass);
                header.addClass('header-xs');
            }else{
                header.removeClass('header-xs').addClass(headerClass);
            }
        }else{
           // you have to restore the previous state here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using "container" div.

The elements inside this div will automatically get resized according to the resolution.